# Django can't load template

Tags: python, django

I've tried this several ways with no luck. If I try to render my view like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import loader

def index(request):
    render(request, loader.get_template('index.html'))
```

I get this error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
```

If I change the code to this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

def index(request):
    content = render_to_string('index.html')
    HttpResponse(content)
```

It actually finds the template and renders it (`content` gets set to the rendered html) but I get this error now:

```
ValueError at /
The view home.controller.index didn't return an HttpResponse object.
```

Here is my folder structure and my settings:

```
myProject/
    settings.py

    home/
       controller.py
       urls.py
       models.py
       templates/
           home/
               index.html
```

Inside my setting.py file I have:

```
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__name__))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = ( os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'home/templates/home'), )

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'gunicorn',
    'home'
)
```

I've tried multiple variations for `TEMPLATE_DIRS` but it's suppose to just pick it up correctly since I have `home` added as an app I thought. Anyone know what's happening here?

**UPDATE**

A combination of things fixed this. First of all a `return` statement is required (*doh*) and I think I was mixing examples of how to render a template. No need to import the loader or render it manually. This is what I wound up with that actually worked:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'home/index.html')
```

Thanks to @lalo and @Rao for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I would have expected the 'index.html' to be right inside of the templates directory, not down a level (under 'home').

Comment: Yeah, I tried that too, but that's what is recommended here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial03/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not returning anything from your view. 
`return HttpResponse(blah)`

Comment: $^$!$(@#~!@...A missing return statement? Seriously??

Comment: @Micah: I and many of my colleagues went through the same thing in our initial days :)

Answer (score 2):

I would try that:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    render(request, 'home/index.html')
```